# Setting a custom attribute

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS app my controller sets customer info like this:

```
$scope.customers = [{'name': 'John', 'customerID': '1'}, {'name': 'Mike', 'customerID': '2'}];
```

How can I store the customer's ID in the custom attribute cid?:

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers" cid=""></div>
```

Comment: sorry to bother you but what you are asking for it's no sense imo if you do like data-cid="{{customer.customerID}}" the value change for all the users and you ended up with the value of the last user id ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers" cid="{{customer.customerID}}"></div>
```

but the valid html way is to add "data-" before cid:

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers" data-cid="{{customer.customerID}}"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work without the handlebars: cid="{{customer.customerID}}"

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers" cid="{{customer.customerID}}"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry but you apparently need the handlebars: cid="{{customer.customerID}}"

Comment: i usualy use it to concat in special attributes (like ng-src), or to display $scope outside of HTML tag